# jq transform JSON resultset by parameter names (no strict order of paramaters)

Tags: json, transform

I already tried a lot, without success.
I'm facing a problem with tranforming the following JSON structure:

JSON:

```
{
   "?xml":{
      "@version":"1.0",
      "@encoding":"UTF-8"

},
   "methodResponse":{
      "params":{
         "param":{
            "value":{
               "struct":{
                  "member":[
                     {
                        "name":"severity",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"Important"

}

},
                     {
                        "name":"product",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"this is a product name"

}

},
                     {
                        "name":"notes",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"Here are some notes"

}

},
                     {
                        "name":"references",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"This is a reference"

}

},
                     {
                        "name":"release",
                        "value":{
                           "i4":"1"

}

},
                     {
                        "name":"last_modified_date",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"2020-03-10 15:21:50.147896"

}

}

]

}

}

}

}

}
}
```

I'd like to filter it by key names like in this transform statement (which already works with one key name):

Transform statement:
`map(.methodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member[] | select(.name == "product" ).value.string as $product| {$product})`

But I'm not sure how the syntax must look like when I want to returning several key names in one statement.

I would expect a result like this one:

```
[
  {
    "product": "This is a product name",
    "release": "1",
    "last_modified_date": "2020-03-09 16:39:39.0"
  }
]
```

I am not quite as familiar with this topic and trying it alone takes forever...
Can anyone help please? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You example isn't valid JSON. Please update your question with a valid JSON example.

Comment: Please also update your question with the JSON expected output.

Comment: I would expect a result like this one[
  {
    "product": "This is a product name",
    "release": "1",
    "last_modified_date": "2020-03-09 16:39:39.0"
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to use `jq`, you need well formated JSON data. The [human JSON tool `hjson`](https://hjson.github.io/) might help on your input data.

```
hjson -j file
```

Extracting the wanted data could be done in the following way:

```
hjson -j file | \
  jq '.methodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member |
      [map({(.name):(.value.string//.value.i4)})|add]'
```

It simply creates ne object base on the `name` and `value` parameters.

Note that if `.value.string` doesn't exist, it uses `.value.i4` with the alternate operator `//`.

Comment: thanks for the input. does that mean that the available keys can be found automatically? When I work with jq play, I receive the error "Cannot index array with string "methodResponse""... https://jqplay.org/s/cxxJBjE3LO
Any idea?